# MediaPlayer mOnPreparedListener is null

Tags: android, media-player, listener

I've a problem with `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()`. The Logcat keep saying that `mOnPreparedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PREPARED message.` According to the MediaPlayer reference this code should work, but it's not:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Settings.this, R.raw.play_samle);       
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        // onPrepared() is never called
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
           mp.start();
        }   

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, you should have :

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Settings.this, R.raw.play_samle);
```

your mp doesn't do anything, as it contains nothing.

Comment: I've changed it according your suggestion, but the problem is still there.

Comment: can you post a complete stacktrace ?

Comment: also, when do you call prepare, and do you set the listener before you call prepare, and what is your target ?

Comment: Here is my stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/hhtd3ZzM . According to: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer there is no need to call MediaPlayer.prepare() because MediaPlayer.create() does it for me. When I'm trying to call prepare() I'm getting another error `E/MediaPlayer(8105): prepareAsync called in state 8`.

Comment: then you probably can ignore the error. just call start immediatly (no need to wait for onPrepared, apparently)